# Excel "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Current Formula *- Working***

> =IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d") > 7,ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0)&IF(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0) > 1," Weeks and "," Week and ")&DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")-(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0)*7)&IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")-(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0)*7) > 1," days"," day"),IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d") = 1,"Tomorrow",DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")&IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d") > 1," days"," day")))

---

**New Formula *- Broken***

> =IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d") > 7,IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7 = 2,"Today",ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0)&IF(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0) > 1," Weeks and "," Week and ")&DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")-(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0)*7)&IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")-(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0)*7) > 1,"days","day"),),IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d") = 1,"Tomorrow",DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")&IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d") > 1," days"," day")))

---

### What I'm Trying To Add

I've got "Tomorrow" working, however now I wish to implement a "Today". To work out if it is "Today", I add the length between the payments as it jumps to the next date if it is today, or in my above version, I go for the weeks between method.

I've broken up my function several times, however I cannot see the problem. Is there a limit to the length of a formula maybe?

Comment: Change `"days","day"),),` to `"days","day")),` ;).

Comment: @shA.t please add your comment as an answer

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose Ok, and Done!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in this part of your formula:

```
IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")-(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0)*7) > 1 ,"days","day"),)
'  ^1st                                                                    ^2nd   ^3rd   ^4th
```

That an `IF` has 4 arguments, an `IF` statement has just 3 arguments, So just use it like this:

```
IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")-(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(TODAY(),U6,"d")/7,0)*7) > 1 ,"days","day"))
```